# Is it possible to boot from a Dos 6.22 USB drive... on a mac pro?

Tags: macos, efi, ms-dos

Using UNetBootin, I've made a bootable DOS 6.22 usb drive from a dos 6.22 bootdisk ISO.

The drive is a 4gb FAT32 drive, formatted on a windows machine.

Is there anyway to boot a 2013 Mac Pro from this drive?  I assume, if it's even possible, I'll have to find a way to enable legacy boot.

Right now i put the drive in, hold down option, power up the machine, but it never lists the USB drive as an option to boot from.

Comment: Macs don't have a 'legacy boot'. They're EFI. They will boot from GUID only. As already mentioned, a VM is the way to go.